# Sonatype nexus 3 Remote connection pending

Tags: nexus, sonatype, nexus3

I recently upgraded to `nexus-3.0.0-M5` for our repository server and I noticed two problems with it.

1. Any repository (hosted) that I create, gets stuck in `Remote Connection Pending` state and it doesn't change no matter what I do.
2. I already have a huge storage/index (approximately 65GB that includes local and remote jars) that I want to use. In Nexus2.x versions, there was a property file called `conf/nexus.properties` where I could specify this and so all upgrades were quite simple and straightforward. But in Nexus3, I can't seem to configure these properties.

Any help in this regard would be useful, been banging my head on the wall since 2 days.

**More Info**

I am not sitting behind a proxy, all connections to my nexus repository are quite direct with authentication. I used [this link](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/admin.html#_repository_management_example) to create a hosted repository (in case I was missing something) but it gets added fine, it just stays stuck in `remote connection pending` state.

I can separate out my local jars from the whole storage area that my previous nexus (nexus2.11) created but even those are about 1.4GB in size. If I could get nexus3 to some-how host these jars automatically, then I can spend the rest of the time in configuring the remote ones (bummer! but as long as my local jars are there, I'll live)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The "connection pending" message is normal in 3.0m6. It just means nothing has been downloaded through the proxy repository yet. Try running a build that retrieves artifacts through the proxy, the status will change once the first file of the artifact is downloaded.

Comment: Thanks for the response. You're right, I was able to download an artifact just fine and the status changed. That solves my first question. Any idea of the other question ?

Comment: Behavior confirmed for version 3.0.2-02.

Comment: Great appreciate for your reply